# How to create a left side bar on APEX 4.0 and open each value in a specific region?

Tags: oracle-apex, sidebar, navigationbar

Im a little newbie working with Aplication Express, I want to create an aplication which its structure could be something like this example.

http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=36648:1:110593396161288::NO

Anyone have some ideas to create it?

I just tried creating a List from Shared Components and then set it in a region with Page Region Template Position 3 and another Chart Region with Page Template Body (3), but in my case the side bar is placed on the right when I want it on the left... I have tried all the Template Position combination as possible.

Also when I click a value from the list, the page is opened on another tab. How can I open it on a specific region? As a frame for example

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Having a left sidebar depends on the page template you select. Some page templates will have a left sidebare, other a right one, others maybe both. And since templates are part of a theme, it may be that some templates under some themes may not have a page template that offers what you'd want.
So the first you need to do is look at what page templates you have available in your chosen theme. You can do this by going to the Shared Components and selecting templates from there. Scroll to the Page Templates and see if you can find one there.
While it's a good guess that the sidebart region will be in position 3, and position 3 is in the sidebar, it's best to verify. You can do that by checking the html of the body of the template. See if there is a region assigned to a sidebar. You'll have to divine this from the markup or an example page and which one it is (position 2? position 3? 4?).
Pro-tip: from the `Shared Components > Templates`, in the report overview, you can preview certain types of templates, such as the page template. Just hit the preview button and you'll get a general idea of the style and the region positioning! When viewing the template in detail, you can also preview from the preview link in the right hand menu list.

As for the list: the example you linked has a list region on the left sidebar, but all those links are links to other pages. Thus, there are as many pages as there are links in the list.
If on your environment the links are causing a new page or tab to be opened up, then that likely means the attribute `target="_blank"` is present on those anchor tags. Again though, this just means that that markup is being generated by the chosen list template. Try another list template (by editing the list, under Source you can chose the template) or take a look at the theme's templates. You can find the markup for the individual list items there.
It'd be better not to concern yourself too much by trying to fiddle around with iframes just yet, because even though that'd be possible it is not an out of the box feature. Unless you're already really familiar with eg javascript I'd stick to page links until you're more familiar with the environment.